# <xs:unique> in XSD does not work

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML like this:

```
<extras>
    <display type="simple_2_lines" address="42"/>
    <temperature name="asd" address="42"/>
    <humidity name="h1" address="42"/>
</extras>
```

I would like set unique property of address attribute like this:

```
<xs:element name="extras">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="display" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element ref="temperature" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element ref="humidity" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>       
    <xs:unique name="unique_address">
        <xs:selector xpath="display | temperature | humidity"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@address"/>
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
```

It works well if all nodes have the same address attribute, but it cannot detect multiple addresses if I set this:

```
<extras>
    <display type="simple_2_lines" address="42"/>
    <temperature name="asd" address="43"/>
    <humidity name="h1" address="42"/>
</extras>
```

How can I write a correct rule?

Comment: For me it is working as expected: a validation error appears if at least two adress attribtues have the same value